# Confusion - The probability of the sum of two dice is $\frac{b-a+1}{36}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, expectation, markov-chains

So the problem is: [image]

The solution writes:

[image]

I understood all the steps except the step where I highlighted. Why is the probability of the $Y$, which is the sum of the two values $\frac{b-a+1}{36}$?

I acknowledged that the $b-a+1$ is the total number of the discrete values from $b$ to $a$, but I thought if $x=k$ is from $a$ to $b$, then $Y$ should be $2(b-a+1)$ since it is the sum of two dice.

Comment: Yes, and this number of values if multiplied with $\frac{1}{36}$ because every elementary event has this probability to occur.

Comment: @Peter Thanks, but why is $(b-a+1) * 1/36$? I thought if $k$ is from $a$ to $b$, then $Y$ should be $2(b-a+1)$ since it is the sum of two dice.

Comment: It seems that you have forgot that $a, b$ are implicit functions of $y$. From the beginning of the calculation, you are given the sum is $y$, and then conclude that the first dice can only take values in between $a$ and $b$. So you already incorporated the information of the second dice, and it has no extra degree of freedom. So given $Y$, you only need to count the number of values that $X$ can take to exhaust the case.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution will follow by analyzing in two segments around $y=7$.

For $y \le 7$, $x$ will be uniformly distributed between $[1,y-1]$, with expected value $\frac{1+y-1}2=\frac{y}2$.

Similarly for $y > 7$, $x$ will be uniformly distributed between $[y-6,6]$, with expected value $\frac{y-6+6}2=\frac{y}2$.

Hence $\mathbb{E}\{X|Y=y\} = y/2$